# на github не подключаются картинки

Tags: github

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина почему не подключает картинки на github-e? загружены нормально,открывает по отдельности но в index.html выдает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так почему у вас в каждой ссылке повторяется домен аж 3 раза?

Comment: @Visman но ведь ссылка на изображение указана корректно

Comment: @Visman Вы не знаете в чем может быть причина что домен повторяется 3 раза?

Comment: А `https://` где?

Comment: @Visman спасибо за внимание. Сделал по Вашему совету и теперь все работает